# Image Saving to Albums working fine in Simulator but gives EXC_BAD_EXCESS on device

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, memory-leaks, uiimage

I want to save an image into albums.
I am doing it using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum API.

Its working perfectly fine on Simulator, but crashes on Device giving EXC_BAD_EXCESS.

I have enables NSZombi.. argument, but it shows no log of any deallocated memory reused.

```
- (IBAction)saveImageOnHDButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    NSArray *subviews = [scroll subviews];
    UIImage *img = [[subviews objectAtIndex:0] image];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

}

Please help..

Thanks

Comment: How are you getting the image from a UIView? Do you have a category on UIView? If you do, can we see it?

Comment: Basically i have a scroll view in which i have added many image view with image, and then on a utton pressed i am picking subview from scroll view and then fetching image from it ..

I guess this what u wanna ask...

Comment: did you implement image:didFinishSavingWithError:? that should give you details on why this is happening

Comment: Yes, i did, but it just gives that log EXC_BAD_EXCESS and crashes, where as on simulator, it goes into didFinish Api and says image saved successfully

Comment: Divide the problem. First insure `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` is working by loading a known image, perhaps from the app bundle.  That way you will know if it is an image problem or a writing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try retaining the image before you save it.